# solution for the Cauchy problem of an elastic bar forced vibrations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for the solution of the following problem:

$\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2}+a^2\frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial x^4}=\Phi(x,t),\quad -\infty<x<\infty, t>0\\ w(t=0)=0,\quad \partial_tw(t=0)=0$

I have found solutions for the finite domain problem; and for the homogeneous, initial condition, Cauchy problem; but cannot find a solution for the forced Cauchy problem.